# Erlang: read non English letters and print them

Tags: csv, unicode, erlang, readfile, non-english

I'm writing a code that read a csv file in erlang.

I get a string from the csv, for example:

Alexander Bubeck|Florian Weißhardt|Matthias Gruhler|Ulrich Reiser

And than I use this commands in order to turn it to list and print it to the terminal:

```
Authors = string:tokens(element(2,Row),[$|]),
io:format("The authors in row ~p are: ~p~n", [Num,Authors])
```

The problem is in this name: Florian Weißhardt

Because it has a non English letter the output is
[70,108,111,114,105,97,110,32,87,101,105,195,159,
104,97,114,100,116]

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try `io:format("The authors in row ~p are: ~s~n", [Num,Authors]).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try convert list to binary in `utf8` [unicode](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html) format:

```erlang
1> 1> Authors = [70,108,111,114,105,97,110,32,87,101,105,195,159, 104,97,114,100,116].
[70,108,111,114,105,97,110,32,87,101,105,195,159,104,97,114, 100,116]
2> io:format("The authors: ~ts~n", [list_to_binary(Authors)]).
The authors: Florian Weißhardt
ok
3> list_to_binary(Authors).
<<"Florian Weißhardt"/utf8>>
```

Comment: It works! but now it prints:

Alexander BubeckFlorian WeißhardtMatthias GruhlerUlrich Reiser  .

Without any space between the different authors (each author was an element in the Authors list). Is there a way to add space? or even present in some kind of data structure (a tuple for example)

Comment: Please provide your full example of list with tuples and with data what you try print out

Comment: This is the input: Alexander Bubeck|Florian Weißhardt|Matthias Gruhler|Ulrich Reiser.    ------

Now the output is:  Alexander BubeckFlorian WeißhardtMatthias GruhlerUlrich Reiser.     ------

I want the output to be: Alexander Bubeck Florian Weißhardt Matthias Gruhler Ulrich Reiser.

or {Alexander Bubeck, Florian Weißhardt, Matthias Gruhler, Ulrich Reiser} 
(Doesn't have to be a tuple, list is also good)

Comment: Can you show a data use `io`? Just call `io:format("~p~n", [YourData]).` and put here the output - this will be helpful. Thanks. P.S. the `input Alexander Bubeck|Florian Weißhardt|Matthias Gruhler|Ulrich Reiser` must have a type, this is a list or binary? A separator `|` is required? etc. The providing the full data from your side will be helpful for trying prepare working solution.

Comment: The output that I show is from this line: `io:format("The authors in row ~p are: ~ts~n", [Num,list_to_binary(Authors)])`
The separator `|` is from the csv file. I download it from a website, and it has about 100k lines to I can't really change it.
the `input Alexander Bubeck|Florian Weißhardt|Matthias Gruhler|Ulrich Reiser` is a string element in a tuple

Comment: You can add spaces use `lists:join/2`. For your case - `Authors = lists:join(" ", string:tokens("Bubeck|Florian Weißhardt|Matthias Gruhler|Ulrich Reiser", [$|])).` and then you can try use `list_to_binary` in `io`. But this point is out of scope of current question(`Erlang: read non English letters and print them`).